# XCODE5.1 C++ static singleton， but multiple instances are created

Tags: c++, xcode, singleton

At first, the code is put in the header file, `timer.h`:

```
static TimerMgr&  Instance() {
    static TimerMgr mgr;
    return mgr;
}
```

and `TimerMgr::TimerMgr` is private.

When program running, I see the constructor be called from every thread, so there are multiple `TimerMgr` instances.

Then I move the function implementation to `timer.cc`, problem solved.

Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 0):

Static variable values in module-level and public variables are preserved for the lifetime of your application.

However, local variables declared with Dim exist only while the procedure in which they are declared is executing. Usually, when a procedure is finished executing, the values of its local variables are not preserved and the memory used by the local variables is reclaimed. The next time the procedure is executed, all its local variables are reinitialized.